# BLE devices not detected by CSR8510 chip

Tags: macos, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, dongle, kernel-extension

I am experiencing lot of troubles detecting BLE devices with a CSR8510 chipset. I don't have much knowledge in bluetooth hardware/stack and osx systems. I made **a lot** of research to solve my problem but I can't find any information specifically related to my issue.

Here is all the informations about my setup :

The dongle is plugged in a Macbook Pro late 2011 (mavericks). I made all the necessary to make the dongle work :

- HCI bootmode
- com.apple.bluetooth.plist deletion and reboot
- I used Bluetooth Explorer to change the Host Controller (default internal chipset -> CSR8510)

Now the dongle is fully recognized by the system, I can use my Magic Mouse (all functionalities work), but I am not able to detect my BLE chest belt ([Runalizer blue](http://www.runalyzer.com/fr/blue.html)).
When I launch a scan with the Device>Low Energy Devices panel in Bluetooth Explorer or the demo app indicated by the belt manufacturer I don't find anything.
Demo app : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/HeartRateMonitor/Introduction/Intro.html

To be fully exhaustive my Xperia SP works perfectly with the belt.

I tried to dig into kernel extensions and I've found in System/Library/IOBluetoothFamily.kext/PlugIns two interesting kext :

- CSRBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport.kext
- CSRHIDTransitionDriver

I do not know if it is relevant or if it could help me but since they start by "CSR" I thaught that it may be related.

I hope someone can help me. It is bothering me so much because I am not able to do the job I was willing to do (gather data from the belt and statistical processing).

Thanks for your attention.